# should I create new folders for each month when to sort uploading files by month in cloudinary?

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

I generate pdf files for each order and save it in cloudinary. But now I want to save it by the current month and year like folder march_2023 etc. so whats the best way to do it in cloudinary ?

Should I create manually all folder until example 2030 and then uploading like this:

```
          const uploadStream = cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload_stream(
              { folder: `${month}_${new Date()}`, resource_type: 'auto' },
              (error, result) => {
                  if (error) {

                      reject(error)
                    return;
                 }
                  resolve(result)
              }
          ).end(data)
```

Or is there a better and easier way to do this ?

Comment: using the folder parameter to specify the folder method is the correct approach.

Comment: @Tom so my solution is ok ?

Comment: @newexe91 yes code wise its fine, the naming convention is up to you.